# Python 3: Print multiple lines to one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched through threads on Stackoverflow and other sites using the Google machine and nothing gives me quite what I am looking for.

I am new programming student using Python 3 so most of my stuff is pretty basic.

I am writing a program that allows me to encrypt and decrypt a text file using the Caeser cipher. Taking a phrase from the user and applying a user given shift.

This is what I am working with right now:

Some of the code is just in there as a place holder until I get further along into my program.

```
import string
print ("1) Encrypt")
print ("2) Decrypt")
print ("3) Decrypt w/o Shift")

Choice = input("Choice: ")

if Choice == '1':
    message = input("Message: ")
    shift = int(input("Shift: "))
    newmsg = ''
    for char in message:
        if char.isupper():
            new = (ord(char)-ord('A')) + shift
            newmsg = chr(new+ord('A'))
            print (newmsg, end="")
        else:
            print(" ")


elif Choice == '2':
    print ("2")

elif Choice == '3':
    print ("3")
```

When I input a test phrase, such as "THIS IS A TEST", it gives me the output, with the correct encryption, but it displays it like this:

```
V
J
K
U

K
U

C

V
G
U
B
```

This is with a "shift" of 2

If I add `end = ' '` to my print statement, it outputs as:

```
V J K U
K U
C
V G U V
```

If I add `end = ''` to my print statement, it outputs as:

```
VJKU
KU
C
VGUV
```

I am looking for an output of:

```
VJKU KU C VGUV
```

I know this is something silly that I am overlooking. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `end=""`, but also add this parameter to the line

```
print(" ")
```

Otherwise, this line will add a newline.

That said, you are probably better off with first collecting the characters in a list, and calling `print()` only once:

```
print("".join(list_of_characters))
```

Yet another approach would be to create a character translation table with `str.maketrans()` and apply it with `str.translate()`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that second print statement. That was the ticket. Thank you very much. Stupid mistake >_<